# Ports being used on Windows XP

Tags: windows, port

I have a MySQL db running, or I want to see if its running.
What command may I use to see which ports are active and what they are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

netstat -ano

Look for the line that is LISTENING on port 3306, and then check the PID.

An easier test it just to try and telnet in from another machine, to port 3306, or try to connect with a MySQL client.

Answer (score 4):

netstat -ab will show the process name for each port.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to netstat you can use a GUI tool like [**ActivePorts**](http://download.cnet.com/Active-Ports/3000-2651_4-29653.html?tag=mncol) or [**Process Hacker**](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) (look at the Network tab) to show open ports and the executables that have opened them.